# redirect drupal 7 site to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, drupal-7

I have Drupal 7 site with default .htaccess file. I need redirect all site possibilities to one https site.
 What I need is:
`http://example.com -> https://example.com 
http://www.example.com -> https://example.com 
https://www.example.com -> https://example.com`

I have tried many options but I still get error: "This Webpage has a redirect loop." 

Default .htaccess looks like:
[.htaccess](http://pastebin.com/gFT5Zxmr)

[Edited] I found solution:
for remove www and retirect to https: 
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]<br>
RewriteRule ^ https%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

for redirect non www to https:
`RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]`

Comment: probably you're bouncing between example.com/www.example.com, or http/https. but since you've provided no sample code, we can't help you.

Comment: You should post your code in the question, instead of external links. That's what the code blocks are for.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try setting the base_url setting in settings.php. By default it's commented out, but you can uncomment it and set it with the desired protocol:

```
$base_url = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];  // NO trailing slash!
```

This has saved me on multiple occasions, in particular when trying to force HTTPS from behind a proxy server, and using the Domain Access module in Drupal 7. I found the solution [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/169326/36512).

Comment: That seems as the most elegant way to achieve this. Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, here's how to force HTTPS redirection via cPanel: https://blog.cpanel.com/force-https-redirection/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone is interested in these redirections (to https AND to www.*):

```
http://example.com to https://www.example.com
```

and

```
http://www.example.com to https://www.example.com
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```